# React Tutorial: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to learn React from the tutorial provided on the React website: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

I am at the step `Taking Turns`, and my code matches theirs completely, but I am getting a Maximum update depth exceeded error, pointing to the `handleClick` function within the `Board` class. From Googling I can see that it's because there is a setState call within the render function, but I am unsure of how to fix the issue. My code is posted below, with a comment above where the issue is occurring.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function Square(props) {
    return (
        <button
            className="square"
            onClick={ props.onClick() }
        >
            {props.value}
        </button>
    );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            squares: Array(9).fill(null),
            xIsNext: true,
        }
    }

    //This is the problem function
    handleClick(i) {
        const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
        squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
        this.setState({
            squares: squares,
            xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
        });
    }

    renderSquare(i) {
        return(
            <Square
                value={this.state.squares[i]}
                onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        const status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="status">{status}</div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(0)}
                    {this.renderSquare(1)}
                    {this.renderSquare(2)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(3)}
                    {this.renderSquare(4)}
                    {this.renderSquare(5)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(6)}
                    {this.renderSquare(7)}
                    {this.renderSquare(8)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="game">
                <div className="game-board">
                    <Board />
                </div>
                <div className="game-info">
                    <div>{/* status */}</div>
                    <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
    <Game />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What is the correct way to solve this issue, and how do I avoid it in my own code in the future?

Comment: `onClick={ props.onClick() }` should just be `onClick={ props.onClick }`. Right now you're calling the function on render, not on click.

Comment: Oh my god I feel so stupid thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your square component, you should not call directly the props.onClick:

```
function Square(props) {
    return (
        <button
            className="square"
            onClick={props.onClick}
        >
            {props.value}
        </button>
    );
}
```

It calls the state at the render and create the infinite loop.